# Safari 14.1 localStorage between tabs is not syncing

Tags: javascript, safari, local-storage, privacy

Here is a minimal case that works in Safari 14.0 (and Chrome, Firefox) but not Safari 14.1:
https://ffvix.csb.app

1. Open the demo in 2 tabs
2. Input some text and press "Submit"
3. Switch to other tab and press "get"

It should be possible to sync messages via localStorage between 2 tabs hosted on the same domain.

Demo code:

```html
    <h1>To localStorage</h1>
    <form id="form">
      <input id="text" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <h1>From localStorage</h1>
    <button id="getout">get</button>
    <p id="out"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      const form = document.getElementById("form");
      const text = document.getElementById("text");
      const out = document.getElementById("out");
      const getout = document.getElementById("getout");

      form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem("test", text.value);
        e.preventDefault();
      });

      function getIt() {
        out.textContent = localStorage.getItem("test");
      }
      getIt();
      getout.addEventListener("click", getIt);
      window.addEventListener("storage", getIt);
    </script>
```

Comment: ave you checked the privacy setting of Safari on your device?

Comment: I think it's default settings. "Prevent cross-site tracking" is on, but this shouldn't be a cross-site thing.

Comment: Do the tabs open in a "new private window"? If yes, change to "new window", exit safari and reopen and check. Should be fixed

Comment: It's not a private window.

Comment: Still, check on 'General' tab, 'Safari opens with' option. There is no reason it should not be shared. Try on an other computer. btw, on which device do you test?

Comment: 13" MacBook Pro M1. 
Safari Version 14.1 (16611.1.21.161.3)
macOS 11.3 (20E232)

Agree that it's something to check. If something is off from the defaults on my computer, I have not found it. Do the repro steps not repro the issue for other people?

Comment: @forresto I can reproduce the issue using your steps to reproduce on Safari Version 14.1 (14611.1.21.161.5) and macOS 10.14.6 (18G9028).

Comment: @mgaw thank you!  ... I see the issue with the latest OS update (Safari Version 14.1 (16611.1.21.161.6)). I don't see the issue (the tabs do sync as expected) with Safari 14.0 and 13.1 via Browserstack. Browserstack doesn't have 14.1 yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed: https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1389493762129375232

Bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225344

I'll update this once I hear of a fix.

---

Fix has shipped as of Version 14.1.2 (16611.3.10.1.6). Tested in two tabs with https://static-misc-3.glitch.me/localstorage-bug/ . The state syncs as expected.

Comment: Today's update does not seem to fix it. (macOS 11.4, Safari Version 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)). Tested with https://static-misc-3.glitch.me/localstorage-bug/

Comment: Gosh, thank goodness I found this thread. I was already doubting myself because I was first looking for a bug in my web application. With Firefox it worked, that's why I've noticed that the tabs in Safari didn't sync the localStorage values.

Comment: we get bug reports related to this issue in the open-source web framework https://abp.io/  . Good to see it's not related to the framework codebase.